# Android Listview Searching

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am making a program in android using `EditText` and `ListView`. I want to search the `ListView` item using `EditText` above. After populate data to `ListView`, when user type text in `EditText`, the `ListView` will scroll to the position start with that text. Example: I have item: **[apple, application, book, boy, car, cat, cash.....]** when I type b in `EditText` then `ListView` will scroll to book. I want to use the `listview.setSelection(position)`, but I don't know how can I get the position from my `EditText` search. I use the code below, it work well, but it seem slow when we search in `EditText`. How can I do this and run smoothly?
Thanks in advances.

---

I use following code:

```
YOUR_EDITTEXT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    //LOGIC MAY DIFFER ACCORDING TO YOUR REQUIREMENT..
    int POSITION = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
        if(list.get(i).startsWith(s.toString()))
        {
            POSITION = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(POSITION);

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Comment: Your code seems okay for me. How many entries do you have in your list? You could pull the s.toString() out from the list but I doubt that that will improve speed much.

Comment: I have more then 20,000 entries. Every time i search in Edittext, the cursor seems works slow, not smooth as simple.

Comment: Now that explains it. Every time you enter a character, onTextChanged is called and does up to 20,000 startsWith() string operations. See my answer for options.

Comment: I would like to refer u this link :  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: @Android this filters the items in the listview. the SO wants to go to the first entry that matches the search query.

Comment: But what i want is to jump to the position of that text in edittext, not filter.

Answer (score 0):

As you have 20,000 list entries, what you currently do is bound to be slow, as you do up to 20,000 `startsWith()` operations, everytime the user changes the text.

So what can you do:

**Simplest solution:**

Do NOT select an entry while the user types. Let him finish and click a search button and only then do what you currently do for every text change.

**Database solution:**

If you have your entries in a database, make a query to get the position. This is much much faster than searching in code. If you don't, can you put it into a database? Is it worth the effect or would the 'Simplest Solution' be good enough?

**Try to be smart:**

You can try to collect information while the user types, and use that for your advantage. Say the user begins to type `Hello`. When `H` is entered you find the first item that starts with `H`, say at position 1000. Now when the user types `e`, you don't have to start from the beginning but can start at position 1000 and so on. Of course you also have to handle cases when the user deletes a character or pastes another text and so on, so there is quite some programming logic involved here.

Comment: I am using database, so how can i make query to get the position of the text ?

Comment: I have to admit I haven't thought about that much (kind of had filtering in mind too). But you can start with a `select _id from <table> where <column> like '<prefix>*' to find out which of your entries start with the given prefix. Adding the same ordering to the sql than you have for the list, you can take the first _id you found (if any). Next you'd have to find the position for that id. This might get a bit tricky and require some support data structure so you could do a binary search or something... Let me know if you need more help and I will think about something later.